Why do i get the error Cannot use import statement outside a module
When i run my test in my next.js app, I get the error   'import { Auth } from "@auth/core"'  'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'. I am not importing { Auth } from "@auth/core" but getting the error . This only happens in components and pages where import auth from auth file in my app. I use  "next": "14.3.0-canary.47", and  "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.20",
I have combed through the docs and stackoverflow, i also added
"next-auth/(.*)": "/node_modules/next-auth/$1", to the moduleameMapper in my jest config file, it did not work,
How do i solve this problem. Below i an example
 import { auth } from "@/auth";
import LoginForm from "@/components/ui/LoginForm";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

async function Login() {
  const session = await auth();
  const user = session?.user;
  if (user) {
    redirect("/");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <h1>Login</h1> {/* <LoginForm /> */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;

Here is my configuration of my jest
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: "./",
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const config = {
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  // Add more setup options before each test is run
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/$1",
    "next-auth/(.*)": "<rootDir>/node_modules/next-auth/$1",
  },
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/(?!(next-auth)/)", // Allow Jest to transform `next-auth`
  ],
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(config);

